# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://physics.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Hmmm. Why would someone vote against moderation elections?

Comment: @Community -1 This isnt a question. Please read the site guidelines

Comment: If I want to nominate someone how do I do that?

Comment: @MBN, we only do self-nominations.

Comment: @solomoan: Community is a known trouble-maker. [Just *look* at the number of down-votes he's cast on SO...](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) Obviously an incurably negative person.

Comment: And you still made Community a moderator? ;) (@solomoan: I can't quite tell if you were being serious, but if so, hopefully you've figured out by now that "Community" is an automated user that represents the system itself.)

Comment: @soloman On metas, posts don't have to be questions.

Comment: @MBN:@reply to a post or comment by the user you have in mind and gently suggest they would make a great mod. Best to do this at meta in a threat closely related to election if possible

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: I was asking because there might be people who want to be a moderator but wouldn't  like to nominate themselves. I didn't have anyone in particular in mind.

Comment: @MBN: Yeah, I was also reluctant to self-nominate, but it's probably intended to avoid someone being forced to it by being to polite to say no... I guess we physicists are just too humble sometimes. But you could still open a meta question like "who'd you like to see as a candidate?"

Comment: @David - and yet have not automated users rights? If you prick them do they not bleed?

Comment: @Martin: well I'm not sure, last time I pricked my computer I got a rather nasty shock ;)

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: that might be a good idea - or at least, something to drum up more interest in the election, seeing as how we're about halfway through the nomination period and still have fewer candidates than open positions.

Comment: @David indeed. I was hoping you and Cedric would be candidates again as well

Comment: @Tobias: Ah, well... I'll be too busy in the near future to be an effective moderator. In fact I was going to request to be replaced, but then elections started anyway. Besides, I'm sure there are enough people here who are tired of my iron fist ;-) (kidding). I'm not sure what Cedric is up to but I haven't heard from him for several weeks.

Comment: @David effectiveness is relative, that lack of time basically applies to me, too. But as long as no one with more spare time (and still a physicist, so I don't know who I am kidding here...) turns up, I'll do my best

Answer (score 7):

Still only 2 candidates :( There are definitely people who I think would make good candidates who haven't yet nominated themselves, especially in the mid-reputation range (1000-5000-ish). Don't be shy!

By the way I know this should be a comment but I'm posting it as an answer as a last-ditch effort to draw some attention to the election.

Comment: There are now 3 candidates, with [my nomination](http://physics.stackexchange.com/election#post-7983)!